# C programming, stm32 uint64_t varibles not working

Tags: c, arrays, 64-bit, stm32

I am haveing troubles with the following. I have an array of uint8_t values.

I am trying to get the first 8 elements of the array into a uint64_t variable.

Therefore I used the following code to achieve that:

```
uint64_t dummy;
int i, x;
uint8_t pRxBuffer[32];
```

...

```
i = 0;
for(x = i; x < (i + 8); x++)
{
    dummy += pRxBuffer[x] << ((x - i) * 8); 
}
```

The problem now is that the variable dummy is treated like a 32 Bit variable. The result of dummy is only the first 32 Bits (so the first 3 elements of the array).

I am using a STM32F303 MCU where this runs on. It is a 32bit machine, but this should not be a problem in my opinion.

Any help is welcomed.

Benjamin

Comment: You need to cast `pRxBuffer[x]` to `uint64_t` as well. Otherwise it will get promoted to `int` and get shifted as one.

Comment: It is not `dummy` that is treated as 32 bits. It is the value you add to it.

Comment: answer, someone? or duplicate?

Comment: duplicate it is.

Comment: As others above have mentioned, the `pRxBuffer[x] << ((x - i) * 8)` subexpression will be evaluated as a 32-bit expression. In that case, when `x >= i + 4`, the shift amount will be greater than or equal to the width of the value being shifted, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It will be evaluated as *`int` (signed)*

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it is working now. But why is the the right side evaluated as a 32 bit expression and not as a 8 bit one, since pRxBuffer is a 8 bit array it should be treated like that. So why the 32 bit ? Is any calculation regardless of variable type treated as a 32 bit expression if no cast is used? I hope my question is clear